# clickable figcaption link on top of image Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

I'm helping a friend setting up a Wordpress page and I have an issue that I can't figure out how to fix.

I have added some image widgets to the sidebar that links to different categories on the site. The problem is that the image text should be on top of the image in a semi transparent box, and this box is not a clickable link. Is it possible to add the same link to the box?

The widget generates an HTML structure like shown in the example below and I have added some CSS to show how the semi transparent text box looks like.

```css
figcaption {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
  top: -235px;
  left: 85px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  text-align:center;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140%
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <a href="some link">
    <img src="http://static.highsnobiety.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/07200609/super-mario-run-iphone-7-01-480x320.jpg">
  </a>
  <figcaption>Super Mario</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: why can you put `figcaption` inside the `<a>` tag? https://jsfiddle.net/qzjgvLfy/

Comment: Hey Grasper

This HTML is automatically generated by Wordpress and I can't seem to find, where I can edit it. Is it possible to do somewhere? Because that would be an easy fix :)

Comment: If you can't change the html, you could do it with javascript. Is that an option?

Comment: create a custom widget and use that instead http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/

Comment: Thanks for the advice Grasper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the html, you'll have to use javascript/jquery to achieve this. In the WordPress widget manager, create a new plain text widget and paste this in:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
  var $sidebar = $('.sidebar'); // change this selector to target your sidebar
  $sidebar.find('figcaption').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('figure').eq(0).find('a').click();
  });
</script>
```

Or, to prevent Wordpress from adding `<p>` put it all on one line:

```
   <script>jQuery(function($){var $sidebar = $('.sidebar'); $sidebar.find('figcaption').on('click',function(e){e.preventDefault();$(this).parents('figure').eq(0).find('a').click();});</script>
```

Comment: Hey Jake! Thanks for the reply! I'm not that experienced in javascript (yet!), so I really appreciate it :) I have tried to copy the javascript into a plain text widget, but the console logs this error: "$sidebar is not a function" in reference to this line: "$sidebar('figcaption').on('click',function(e){"

Comment: No worries! :) This time the console logs " Unexpected token ( " in reference to the parentheses in "  $sidebar.('figcaption')...... "

I'm sorry to bother you again with this!

Comment: ok, try now. This is what happens when you hand out code without even testing it once. ;)

Comment: Haha that's true :P The good news is that there are no errors in the console! But nothing happens when I click on the box. I can see that the script tags are automatically wrapped inside a <p> tag. Can that be causing the issue?

Comment: Yeah, stupid wordpress wrapping those script tags, eh? Put it all on one line.

Comment: I just tested this, and it works: `<script>jQuery('.sidebar').find('figcaption').on('click',function(e){ window.location = jQuery(this).parents('figure').eq(0).find('a').attr('href') });</script>`

Comment: Yeah it works perfectly when it's put into the console! It still doesn't work when I add the script through the widget, but I will look into that :) Thank you so much for your help and patience Jake! You're a lifesaver! :)

Comment: Ok, that's because jquery isn't loaded yet. So then, you'll want `<script>jQuery(function(){jQuery('.sidebar').find('figcaption').on('click',fun‌​ction(e){ window.location = jQuery(this).parents('figure').eq(0).find('a').attr('href') });});</script>`

Comment: And now it works! Thanks again! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 10):

Appearance > Customise > Additional CSS

```
figcaption
{
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: That's a much better solution than messing with JS. Just act as if the figcaption wasn't there.

Comment: This seems like the best solution ! Thanks !